# Unable install Gulp using npm in Windows

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to install Gulp using npm in Windows 8 using following command in Command Prompt:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

And I am getting following error in the command prompt

```
C:\windows\system32>npm install gulp -g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

I have set the nodeJs executable file path in the PATH environmental variable. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like it's having trouble getting to registry.npmjs.org:443. Can you try navigating to https://registry.npmjs.org/ and seeing if you can access it.

Comment: I could not able to access the link [registry.npmjs.org](https://registry.npmjs.org/) . It is just returning a JSON value in the browser.

Comment: Are you using a proxy ?

Comment: If it's returning JSON, that means it is accessible. As asked above, it might be your browser is going through a proxy.

Comment: Are you using the node cmd? I had this problem until I was told about it

Comment: We are not using any proxy.

Comment: I am using windows cmd only. I have installed nodeJs before trying to install Gulp.

Comment: If you run the npm install using the nodejs cmd, it should run fine

Comment: I tried running the command from nodejs cmd, it is throwing error as "npm should be run outside of the node repl in your normal shell"

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a proxy issue too. Try doing this:

```
npm config set proxy http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>
npm config set https-proxy http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>
```

Change the values surrounded with **<>** with your proxy data (if you don't use a username to login just delete that part) and try it.

Comment: For example, for out corporate proxy it was smth like:
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080. Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a proxy issue, try to put this in your cmd :

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```